# Take user to settings screen?

Tags: java, android, database, string, algorithm

I want to take the user to the settings screen **of my application** where they can change permissions and clear data/cache. How can I do that?

I have looked all over the web, and all I see is a way to get to the application settings (intent: `ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS`), but I want to go to **my** application settings.

### How can I go to my application specific settings programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to go  [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmrOU.png), right?

There are several ways of doing that.But my favorite way of doing that is below

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
```